# Conjugacy classes in a group of order $p^aq^b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\Pi_e(G)$ denotes the set of all orders of elements (except the identity element) in a group $G$. Is there a group $G$ with the following properties:

i) $|G|=p^aq^b$ ($p$ and $q$ are distinct primes)

ii) $|\Pi_e(G)|=3$

iii) $Z(G)=1$

iv) The union of any four distinct non-trivial conjugacy classes of $G$ together with 1 is a subgroup of it.

If it exists, then what can we say about $G$? Is it possible to classify all the groups $G$ satisfying in above properties?

Comment: Am I right that (ii)  & (iii) imply (i)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edit it now.

Comment: Are $p,q,a,b$ fixed? The answer may depend on them.

Comment: No, they are arbitrary with $a,b \geq 1$.

Comment: In ii) the only possible orders are $p, q, pq$ The first two because of the Sylow theorems and the third case follows from this. Thus the Sylow subgroups are elementary abelian isomorphic to  $Z_p^a$, $Z_q^b$.

Comment: I didn't understand why the third possible order is $pq$ and how it implies that the Sylow subgroups are abelian?

Comment: It is easy to satisfy i), ii) and iii), but iv) seems very difficult to satisfy. In fact $S_4$ satisfies all of these conditions, but that is because it only has four nontrivial classes altogether. I don't know any other examples. What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: @M.R. If there is an element $a$ of order say $p^xq^y$ then $b=a^{p^x}$ has order $q^y$.

Comment: You proved that if $G$ has an element of order $p^xq^y$, then $x=y=1$. But it may happen that $G$ has elements of prime power orders. For example in a dihedral group of order $2p^2$, the only orders are $1,2,p,p^2$.

Comment: @M.R. You are correct: either the three orders are $p,q,pq$ or $p,p^2,q$.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Would you please give me the classification of groups satisfy in cases i), ii) and iii)?